# Streaming JSON data into BigQuery using BigQuery Storage Write API with Python client library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there a way one can load JSON data into Bigquery using Python?. I will appreciate ideas on how this can be achieved since the only [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/learn-how-stream-json-data-bigquery-using-new-bigquery-storage-write-api)  am coming across are for Java Client Library

Thank You !!

Comment: Have a look at [Python SDK Documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client) for BigQuery

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71209828/python-bigquery-storage-write-retry-strategy-when-writing-to-default-stream